# Simple unital ring which is not a domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

We define for rings with unity:

- **Simple:** No non-trivial bilateral ideals.
- **Domain:** No non-trivial zero divisors.

Are all simple rings domains? Conversely, are there any non-domain simple rings?

For commutative rings the question is trivial, as simple implies field. But I can't derive the existence of a non-trivial bilateral ideal from the existence of a non-trivial zero divisor.

Comment: [DaRT search](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=3&L=8) for simple nondomain rings.

Comment: The second thing you said is not *conversely* to the first thing. The converse would be "are all domains simple rings."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ring of $n\times n$ matrices over some field has just two bilateral ideals (zero and the whole ring), but it contains non-trivial zero divisors for all $n\ge2$.

Comment: Thanks. Matrices were my first thought, but for some reason I assumed they wouldn't be simple. Shows what I know.